# Check any structure members for 0

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a structure that contains x amount of integers, It is required that every last one of them be non-zero. Here's my structure:

```
struct thingy_t{
    int a, b, c /* and so on */;

    bool init();
};
```

Over time I will be adding many other members to the structure, which makes it an issue if I forget to check if it's non-zero. That's why I wanted to automate it for every member.

In my `init` function, it attempts to get values for the members, and return false if any of them are 0.

So far I have this:

```
bool thingy_t::init(){
    a = GetValue(/* blah blah */); // Will return 0 if it can't find anything
    b = GetValue(/* other blah */);
    /* and so on */

    // Check if any value is zero
    for(int* i = (int*)this
    ; i < (int*)((char*)this + sizeof(interfaces_t))
    ; i++){
        if(!*i) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am looking for a better way of doing this that would be more readable and more memory safe, as I am playing with fire(pointers) in a way they probably aren't intended.

Also, sorry for the `for` loop, I tried to make it more readable by wrapping it, but I probably made it worse.

Comment: If you're changing your data types "*over time*" you have bigger problems then zero values. Make a better design.

Comment: How about making a wrapper-class, that behaves as an `int` (with the help of the correct overloaded operators) but have a constraint that it can't be zero. Then use this `nonzero_int` instead of `int` for your members.

Comment: Or if you make an array of `int` instead, you can easily check if they're all non-zero.

Comment: @Amit I'm not changing the data types, I am changing the amount of data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It can't just not be zero, it has to be _correct_, hence why I'm returning zero if it cannot find what I'm looking for.

Comment: "*Changing the amount of data*" - the way you do it *is* changing the type. If you need to modify the definition, it's a new type

Comment: @JamesRoot Sadly, I cannot use an array since all the variables have a name that, if I replace with an index in an array, won't make it much readable elsewhere.

Comment: @Amit Fair enough, however, the amount of data doesn't matter since that's easily covered by the sizeof operator.

Comment: @notsign Make an `enum` that matches the variable name to index, like `enum VAR { a = 0, b = 1, c = 2}`

Comment: @JamesRoot Not a half bad idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question while enjoying a nice breakfast.

Here's how I solved it:

```
struct thingy_t{
    union{
        struct{
            int a, b, c;
        }
        int arr[3];
    }
}
```

That way I can access variables via. their name and also their index in an array so I can check if each value is non-zero easier (creds: James Root for the array inspiration)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a natural way to iterate over the struct and check for certain values of the members you have, so the better option for you, in my opinion, should be either make a better design for your task or make sure that you check for incorrect values on each access to that struct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simple implement the type to contain an array of `int` or (possibly better) a standard container.

If the number of values is specified at compile time ....

```
 struct thingy_t
 {
     int x[number];    

     bool all_non_zero() const;

 };

 bool thingy_t::all_non_zero() const
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
        if (!number[i]) return false;
     return true;         
 }
```

If the number is not specified at compile time, I'd use a standard container

```
 struct thingy_t
 {
     std::vector<int> x;

     thingy_t(std::size_t size) : x(size) {};
     bool all_non_zero() const;

 };

 bool thingy_t::all_non_zero() const
 {
     for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = x.begin(), end = x.end();
          it != end number; ++it)
        if (!(*it)) return false;
     return true;         
 }
```

The above works for all versions of C++, but may be simplified in C++11 or later.

```
 bool thingy_t::all_non_zero() const
 {
     for (const auto &element : x)
         if (!element) return false;
     return true;         
 }
```

Naturally, you will need other functions to actually store values in the array or vector.

The code won't change if the number of integers changes.   You will need to somehow track separately the meaning of each element.